# Не понимаю, как решить вопрос на Яндекс Практикуме

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Измените код Анфисы. Оставьте вывод на экран, т.е. вызовы функции print(), только в одном месте — в основном теле программы. Эти вызовы уже написаны в предварительном коде задания.
Все прошлые выводы на экран — в функциях show_count_friends() и process_query() — замените на возвращения результатов из функции оператором return.

```py
FRIENDS = ['Серёга', 'Соня', 'Дима', 'Алина', 'Егор']


def show_count_friends(count_friends):
    if count_friends == 1:
        print('У тебя 1 друг')
    elif 2 <= count_friends <= 4:
        print('У тебя ' + str(count_friends) + ' друга')
    elif count_friends >= 5:
        print('У тебя ' + str(count_friends) + ' друзей')


def process_query(query):
    if query == 'Сколько у меня друзей?':
        count = len(FRIENDS)
        show_count_friends(count)
    elif query == 'Кто все мои друзья?':
        friends_string = ', '.join(FRIENDS)
        print('Твои друзья: ' + friends_string)
    else:
        print('<неизвестный запрос>')


# Внимание! Это те самые вызовы, которые не надо трогать
print(process_query('Сколько у меня друзей?'))
print(process_query('Кто все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Как меня зовут?'))
```

Comment: Уже менял в первом и втором блоках кода print на return. Но проходит..

Comment: Конечно, не проходит. Нужно взять учебник и прочитать, что такое return и как им пользоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции должны возвращать значения, иначе вернется `None`:

```
FRIENDS = ['Серёга', 'Соня', 'Дима', 'Алина', 'Егор']


def show_count_friends(count_friends):
    if count_friends == 1:
        return 'У тебя 1 друг'
    elif 2 <= count_friends <= 4:
        return 'У тебя ' + str(count_friends) + ' друга'
    elif count_friends >= 5:
        return 'У тебя ' + str(count_friends) + ' друзей'


def process_query(query):
    if query == 'Сколько у меня друзей?':
        count = len(FRIENDS)
        return show_count_friends(count)
    elif query == 'Кто все мои друзья?':
        friends_string = ', '.join(FRIENDS)
        return 'Твои друзья: ' + friends_string
    else:
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'


# Внимание! Это те самые вызовы, которые не надо трогать
print(process_query('Сколько у меня друзей?'))
print(process_query('Кто все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Как меня зовут?'))
```